# Map shared library into physical memory

Tags: operating-system, virtual-memory

Recently,I've been reading "computer systems". It says the shared library is mapped to the same page of physical memory as a shared object between processes, including its .data section and .text section. And the write operation on a shared object in one process can also be "shared" by another process. Here is the problem: when building a shared library, the data section begins with a GOT, which contains the addresses of the global variables. And the dynamic loader is in charge of filling out the addresses for each program that is linked with the shared library, which means writing the addresses on the corresponding page of physical memory, so how can it not affect another process that is linked with the shared library, as it contains a whole different GOT.

Answer (score 0):

Values in GOT reference virtual memory not physical memory. Thus the shared library can be mapped into the same virtual memory address in multiple processes multiple times without the need for any further relocation using the virtual addresses set by the [linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)).

If the virtual memory can not be mapped because it is already occupied by something else, the [loader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loader_(computing)) will map the library into a free virtual memory region and it will create a copy and relocate it.

Answer (score 0):

> Recently,I've been reading "computer systems". It says the shared library is mapped to the same page of physical memory as a shared object between processes, including its .data section and .text section. And the write operation on a shared object in one process can also be "shared" by another process.

The behavior of shared libraries is entirely system dependent. To begin with, shared libraries may or may not share physical memory when used with multiple processes. On system where they do share memory, the shared library is usually installed by the operating system in some way to indicate the preferred version of the library. Otherwise, you'd have a huge security hole.

Some systems do share data in shared libraries. That was a monster pain in early Windoze. However, no reliable system would permit that without some kind of installation.